# SSL/TLS handshake from .NET to APNs - remote certificate is invalid

Tags: .net, windows, ssl, service, apple-push-notifications

I'm connecting to *Apple Push Notification Service (APNs)* from the *.NET Framework* using a `SslStream`. I'm connecting using the `Binary Provider API`. As part of the initial handshake, the `SslStream` does an `AuthenticateAsClient` on the network stream. This is the code for that:

```
_sslStream = new SslStream(_tcpClient.GetStream());
_sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_url,
    new X509CertificateCollection { _certificate },
    SslProtocols.Tls,
    true);
```

Where `_url` is the *APNs* hostname and `_certificate` the push certificate of the app. On most machines (running a version of Windows Server), this is accepted and communication can continue. However, on some machines, this will fail. This is the exact error:

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

The code runs as *Windows Service* under the *Local System* privileges. When the **exact same code** runs as command-line application under a local user, the **handshake is accepted** and communication can continue. Running the same command-line application under *Local System* using `pexec -i -s` causes the same error . I've checked if there are differences in the certificate stores between *Local Computer* and the *Current User*, but there are none.

A "workaround" was also tested. In this changed form, the code shown earlier was adapted to completely ignore certificates. This does exactly as you'd expect; the received certificates are not checked and communication can continue. This is what that looks like:

```
_sslStream = new SslStream(_tcpClient.GetStream(), false, (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true);
_sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_url,
    new X509CertificateCollection { _certificate },
    SslProtocols.Tls,
    false);
```

Of course, disabling security is a bad idea. What could be causing the handshake to break?!

Comment: Since you note the results differ based on which user runs it, maybe the given certificate / AC certificate is only stored in one user truststore and not the others (I do not know how that works under Windows).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek There are indeed differences, each user has its own certificate store. I manually compared the certificate store of each user and found no differences. Both are identical. Unless there are hidden certificates of some kind, I don't think this is it. And there may very well be hidden certificates.. because Windows does some weird shit.

Comment: You could try to find which validation has failed by enabling `System.Net` trace. This [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure/) could help

Comment: At last resort, run a network capture for both of the cases, but you will need some tweaking on the client side to store the client random and master key in order for later to be able to import the traces in Wireshark with the associated cryptographic data so that it could decrypt it and show you both `Certificate` message and compare them. Alternatively run a simple local TLS server like `openssl s_server` or `stunnel` with full verbosity and have your application connect to it to see what certificates it sends (but it may be different than when using the true server; or have a proxy).

Comment: Since Local System user is the desired user account to execute the application, I think it's a better practice to store the certificate in the Local Machine cert store, instead of user specific. If the Local System user is missing permissions to access the certificate, it will be much easier to troubleshoot such an issue when using Local Machine.

Comment: Does the `errors` object in your certification validation lamda contain any value? The validation callback should give you the exact certificate that is failing and the reason for failure.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Instead of blindly returns `true`, you can obviously write your own handler to assert the remote certificate (CA, thumbprint and so on).

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is to find which requirements are not being met.
You can use this: 
https://github.com/rodneyviana/blogdemos/blob/master/TestServerCertificate.zip

- Unzip it anywhere. Make sure the application is unblocked
  (right-click, properties and check Unblock if present)
- Open a command prompt as administrator
- Run this to get into the system user context: c:\sysinternals\PsExec
  -i -s cmd.exe
- In the new prompt window, move to the folder where you extracted the
  tool
- Run using this syntax: TestServerCertificate [host] [port]
- This will save a log file and the certificates from the certificate
  chain to a temp folder.

See example below:

```
c:\tools>whoami
nt authority\system

c:\tools>TestServerCertificate.exe www.microsoft.com 443
Verify Certificate Details
==========================


Writing logs to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\certchain_e9ab7362-e5ba-4adc-b47c-7f28c0eddbfc\output.log

c:\tools>notepad C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\certchain_e9ab7362-e5ba-4adc-b47c-7f28c0eddbfc\output.log
```

This is the actual log from the command above (no errors, of course):

```
Getting certificate from www.microsoft.com 443
TLS Protocol: Tls12
Strength 256

Certificate at www.microsoft.com

Thumbprint: 8FBE50987D59F8C023492162238250C2ED18176A
Subject: CN=www.microsoft.com, OU=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US
Friendly Name: 
Issuer name: CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 4, OU=Microsoft IT, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Valid until: 1/16/2020 3:24:02 PM
Certificate is valid: True
Number of extensions: 10

Writing Certificate: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\certchain_e9ab7362-e5ba-4adc-b47c-7f28c0eddbfc\certificate_8FBE50987D59F8C023492162238250C2ED18176A.cer

WARNING: Certificate was not found in any location store

Chain Information
=================
Chain revocation flag: ExcludeRoot
Chain revocation mode: Online
Chain verification flag: NoFlag
Chain verification time: 8/11/2018 1:57:30 AM
Chain status length: 0
Chain application policy count: 0
Chain certificate policy count: 0 

Chain Element Information
Number of chain elements: 3


Intermediate Certificate
==============================================

Element thumbprint: 8A38755D0996823FE8FA3116A277CE446EAC4E99
Element subject: CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 4, OU=Microsoft IT, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Friendly Name: 
Element issuer name: CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
Element certificate valid until: 5/20/2024 7:52:38 AM
Element certificate is valid: True
Element error status length: 0
Element information: 
Number of element extensions: 8

Writing Certificate: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\certchain_e9ab7362-e5ba-4adc-b47c-7f28c0eddbfc\Intermediate_8A38755D0996823FE8FA3116A277CE446EAC4E99.cer
Information: Certificate was found installed in store(s) -  CurrentUser\CA

ROOT Certificate
==============================================

Element thumbprint: D4DE20D05E66FC53FE1A50882C78DB2852CAE474
Element subject: CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
Friendly Name: DigiCert Baltimore Root
Element issuer name: CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
Element certificate valid until: 5/12/2025 6:59:00 PM
Element certificate is valid: True
Element error status length: 0
Element information: 
Number of element extensions: 3

Writing Certificate: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\certchain_e9ab7362-e5ba-4adc-b47c-7f28c0eddbfc\ROOT_D4DE20D05E66FC53FE1A50882C78DB2852CAE474.cer
Information: Certificate was found installed in store(s) -  CurrentUser\AuthRoot LocalMachine\AuthRoot CurrentUser\Root LocalMachine\Root
============= End of Report =============
```

If the problem is not clear in the log, post it here for analysis.

- This requires .NET 4.5 or newer. If you do not have it, add System.Net traces to your config file and repro the issue, then post the file here for analysis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing